# How do I add a public instance method of priceAfterDiscount which returns the price after discount

Tags: java, oop

Procedural Programming (Not OOP)

The first method calculateRevenue calculates and returns the total revenue
The second method printResult prints the number visitors and the total revenue. Format the output.

```
public class Museum {
    static final double PRICE=12.5;
    static final double GIFT=8.99;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
    int visitors;
    double totalRevenue;

    System.out.print("Enter number of visitors: ");
    visitors= console.nextInt();  

    /* How do I execute this? */

    //assume the user input is valid

    // Call calculateRevenue method
    //Call calculatePrintResult method


   // TODO code application logic here
    }  
}
```

---

Comment: Based on the title, are you facing problem to call a public instance method from your main function or you dont understand how to write the logic to calclulate price after dicount?

Comment: Can you please tell us the what should be out put result as you wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Museum {
    static final double PRICE = 12.5;
    static final double GIFT = 8.99;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      int visitors;
      double totalRevenue;

      System.out.print("Enter number of visitors: ");
      visitors = console.nextInt();

      totalRevenue = calculateRevenue(visitors);
      calculatePrintResult(visitors);

  }

  public  static double calculateRevenue(int visitors) {
      return visitors * PRICE;
  }

  public static void calculatePrintResult(int visitors) {
      System.out.println(visitors * PRICE);
  }
}
```